# How to render a ndb StringProperty field as a textarea widget using wtforms on App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, wtforms

Example code:

```
# model
class Foos(ndb.Model):
    bar = ndb.StringProperty()


# handler
class FoosHandler(BaseHandler):
    def get(self):
        form = model_form(Foos)
        self.render('form.html', form=form)

# template
{{ form.bar() }}
```

According to wtforms documentation, any StringProperty field that has the attribute "multiline=True" will be rendered with the TextArea widget.

However, multiline=True is not supported in NDB (only DB) and so this doesn't work.

Is there a way to specify what widget a field should be rendered with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

wtforms `Fields` can be passed 'widget' as a parameter to override the class used to render them. When using `model_form`, you can pass a dict of `field_args`, where each key is the model-property, and the value is a dict that is used as the keyword-args when creating the field:

```
form = model_form(Foos, field_args={'bar': {'widget': wtforms.widgets.TextArea()}})
```